# How to end a pop up when data is entered in a different cell

Tags: excel, vba, popup

Below is the VBA I'm using.

```
Dim DateDueCol As Range

Dim DateDue As Range

Dim NotificationMsg As String

Set DateDueCol = Range("o3:o100") 'the range of cells that contain your due dates

For Each DateDue In DateDueCol

    'Change o3 to the cell for bring forward reminder days in your data

    If DateDue <> "" And Date >= DateDue - Range("z3") Then

    'Change the offset value to pick up the invoice number column in your data

        NotificationMsg = NotificationMsg & " " & DateDue.Offset(0, -14)

    End If

Next DateDue

If NotificationMsg = "" Then

    MsgBox "There are none Expected to Return to Work Today."

Else: MsgBox "The following are Expected Return to Work in Two Days: " & NotificationMsg

End If

End Sub
```

I want the pop up to stop if a date is entered in a specific cell.

Comment: What's the `specific cell`? Please share the whole Sub procedure in your post.

Comment: the column to the right.  Column A has a begin date and column B has an end date.

Comment: Still don't know what's your expected result. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)